# Sometimes no index on category pages

Tags: magento-1.9, cache, full-page-cache, memcached, apc

I use magento 1.9.3.7 with memcached, apc, Lesti FPC and CreareSEO and other but I think only this plugin can do it.
Site work without any changes and editing but sometimes yandex robot find NOINDEX tag on category page.
Today I see it on one category page myself (other pages work correctly)

```
`<meta name="robots" content="NOINDEX,FOLLOW"/>`
```

after just rebuild cache I have

```
`<meta name="robots" content="INDEX,FOLLOW"/>`
```

nothing more changes.. 
Where I can find this problem? Have you any idea?

Comment: Do you have multi-store setup? Please check System -> Configuration -> Design -> HTML Head -> Default Robots for all stores, in Magento admin.

Comment: Thank's yes I use multi-store and I use my robots plugin for robots.txt but it's tag in page.. not in robots.txt
and I can't use default robots for all store because i need diferent directive host and sitemap for each domain..

Comment: now i disabled possibility noindex in CreareSEO and don't see more this error.